# GTM 52 Exercise 4.7

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

[image]

The question is GTM 52 Exercise 4.7.

We can choose affine open subset $X_
i\subset X$ with $P\in X_i$ and affine open subset $Y_
i\subset Y$ with $Q\in Y_i$.

Because $\mathcal O_{P,X}\cong \mathcal O_{Q,Y}$ as $k-$algebras, it's easy to show $K(X_i)\cong K(Y_i)$ as $k-$algebras by Theorem 3.2,  then there are open subsets $U\subset X_i$ and $V\subset Y_i$ with $U$ is isomorphic to $V$, but how to show $P\in U,Q\in V$ and the isomorphism sends $P$ to $Q$?

Answer (score 2):

We would like to show that the rational map $\phi : X\to Y$ as in the proof of theorem 4.4 is defined at $P$ and $\phi (P)=Q$, and similarly for $\psi :Y\to X$. Then the construction of $U\subset  X, V\subset Y, U\simeq V$ in corollary 4.5 (i)$\implies $(ii) shows $P\in U, Q\in V$.

Assume $Y$ is affine. We have the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A(Y) @. \\ @V\alpha VV \\ \mathcal{O}_Q @>\sim > \beta> \mathcal{O}_P\\ @VVV @V\gamma VV \\ K(Y)@>\sim>\theta > K(X).
\end{CD}
Let $y_1,\dots y_n$ be generators for $A(Y)$ as in theorem 4.4. Since $\theta (y_i)=\gamma (\beta \alpha (y_i)) \in \mathcal{O}_P$, $\theta (y_i)$ are defined and regular at $P$. $y_i-y_i(Q) $ have zero at $Q \implies y_i-y_i(Q) \in \mathfrak{m}_Q \implies \beta( y_i-y_i(Q))\in \mathfrak{m}_P \implies \theta(y_i-y_i(Q))(P)=0\implies\theta(y_i)(P)=y_i(Q)\implies\phi(P)=Q.$ The last implication follows from the proof of Proposition 3.5.